# QT CAN BUS, SocketCAN cannot read CAN frames

Tags: c++, qt, can-bus, socketcan, qt5.7

I have troubles reading CAN frames using readFrame() method in QT.

My code for initialization:

```
#include <QCanBusFrame>
#include <QCanBus>
#include <QCanBusDevice>

CANSend::CANSend(QString interface){

CANdevice = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice("socketcan", interface);
if (!CANdevice->connectDevice()) {}

 }
```

code for sending data - everything works correctly

```
void CANSend::send_pos(uint16_t pos)
{
QCanBusFrame frame;
frame.setFrameId(1024);
QByteArray payload;
payload[0]=0;
payload[1]=pos>>8;
payload[2]=pos;

frame.setPayload(payload);
CANdevice->writeFrame(frame);
}
```

code for reading data

```
int CANSend::check_messages(){

 const QCanBusFrame frame = CANdevice->readFrame();

 const qint8 dataLength = frame.payload().size();

 const qint32 id = frame.frameId();

 return id;
}
```

during debugging I always get
    frame = @0x7fffffffdf10,
    dataLength = 0,
    id = 0,

So, even though I can clearly see incomming packets via candump command and also in QT CANBUS example, I never receive anything.

Can you help me, please? Thanks.

Comment: Try receiving frames by connecting to the slot `QCanBusDevice::framesReceived`.